# How to pass data from port.on function to external variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am trying to pass contents of data to an external variable 
 using the line `lottoNumber = rndNum;`. Please see the code below.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyACM0', {
  baudRate: 9600, parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline("\n\r")
});

var rndNum = -1;
var lottoNumber = -99;

// Read the port data
port.on('data', function(data) {
  const buf = Buffer.from(data);
  rndNum = buf.readUInt8(0,1);
  if((rndNum > 0) && (rndNum < 41)) {
    lottoNumber = rndNum;
    port.close(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
});

console.log(lottoNumber);
```

The expected output from `console.log(lottoNumber);` is a number from `1-40` but the actual output is `-99` which is wrong. How do I pass contents of `rndNum` to `lottoNumber`? Thanks for any help!.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with serialport, but you wont be able to access the new variable declaration outside of the scope of the function port.on() unless you call it.

```
var lottoNumber = -99

function portable(data){
  var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.max(data))
  lottoNumber = rndNum;
}

console.log(lottoNumber) // will log -99
```

the variable lottoNumber is not in the scope of portable()

```
portable(41)
console.log(lottoNumber) // will log to the console random numbers only if portable() is called
```

[MDN scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)